# Maven Mirror - how to bypass if mirror host is not available?

Tags: maven, vpn

I have a maven mirror repository (Archiva)
e.g.

```
<settings>
   <mirrors>     
        <mirror>
        <id>archiva</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://myMirrorHost:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>     
    </mirror>
       </mirrors>
       ...
```

However this is behind a VPN, and sometimes I rather not use it / can't connect to the VPM

The issue is when building outside the VPN, I get this error

> myMirrorHost: Unknown host myMirrorHost -> [Help 1]

When I would like it instead to timeout / not use the mirror if not found

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running the build in off-line mode when not connected to the VPN

```
mvn -o clean package
```

Another option is to have a second Maven settings file for use when you're connected to a different network:

```
mvn -s $HOME/.m2/settings-alternative.xml clean package
```

In this case I'd also recommend specifying an alternative local repository location (within the settings file), so as to avoid build confusion.

Comment: saved me. I tried few months ago but could not bypass it, this is awesome!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation and I changed the mirror settings to mirror central, not *:

```
<mirrors>     
 <mirror>
  <id>archiva</id>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://myMirrorHost:8080/archiva/repository/internal</url>     
 </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Then in a profile, I define another repository, e.g. ibiblio:

```
<profile>
  <id>myprofile</id>

 <activation>
  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
 </activation>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ibiblio.org</id>
       <name>ibiblio Mirror of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</name>
       <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url> 
    </repository>
  </repositories>  
</profile>
```

Now when something is not found in the mirror, or the mirror host is not reachable, maven tries the other repository (which is a mirror of central).

Comment: If you just put the url of Maven in your alternative repository, you'll be able to bypass the mirror whenever it's not available. Only the id shouldn't be `central`

Answer (score 0):

I've always used a similar approach to [Mark's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627757/140037) which I wrote a script for to handle copying different configurations or removing the one that is there.

Basic usage is to first write a configuration file of the form `~/.m2/settings.<config>.xml` where `<config>` is the name of a configuration, then setting the config by invoking `setmvn [config]`, not specifying will remove the config in place. This will symlink to the configuration file so if your tools modify the current config it will modify the config file currently in place.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ "$#" -lt 2 ] || {
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [profile-name]" >&2
    exit 1
}

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    if [ -f ~/.m2/settings.xml ] ; then
        echo "Configuration removed."
        rm -f ~/.m2/settings.xml
    else
        echo "Configuration not in place, nothing to do." >&2
    fi
else
    if [ -f ~/.m2/"settings.$1.xml" ] ; then
        [ -f ~/.m2/settings.xml ] && rm -f ~/.m2/settings.xml
        ln -s ~/.m2/"settings.$1.xml" ~/.m2/settings.xml
        echo "Configuration set to $1."
    else
        echo "Configuration not found: $1" >&2
        exit 2
    fi
fi
```